# bonobo git repo - can't add new users from admin account

Tags: asp.net, git, bonobo

I installed bonobo on my server and I can create repos and commit/push them and do all the operations with the admin account (also creating new team) except adding new users.

googling I didn't find anybody that had my problem in the past so I checked my web.config that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    
    <add key="UserConfiguration" value="C:\websites\git\home\App_Data\config.xml" />
    <add key="DefaultRepositoriesDirectory" value="C:\websites\git\home\App_Data\Repositories" />
    <add key="GitPath" value="C:\websites\git\home\App_Data\Git\git.exe" />
    <add key="GitServerPath" value="http://git.ofunwebservices.com/home/" />
    
    <add key="ShouldImportWindowsUserAsAdministrator" value="false" />
    <add key="ActiveDirectoryIntegration" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BonoboGitServerContext" connectionString="Data Source=C:\websites\git\home\App_Data\Bonobo.Git.Server.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="errorListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="App_Data/Bonobo.Git.Server.Errors.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="EFRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="EFRoleProvider" type="Bonobo.Git.Server.Security.EFRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4194304" />
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
          <clear />          
        </fileExtensions>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <clear />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

[image: screenshot]

how can I create users with bonobo?

Answer (score 1):

just after switching the line

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

to

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

magically, the "Create new user" appears